# Parser Error Message: Could not load type from assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add a `roleprovider` for my application but i am having troubles  because of the parser error.

Here are my files:

[image]

This is my web config:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider ="roleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="roleprovider"  type="MvcApplication6.roleprovider,MvcApplication6"/>
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

I kept on getting that `Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'roleprovider' from assembly 'MvcApplication6'`.

I tried several methods such as adding to `App_code`.

How do i resolve this issue? I tried the other solutions but they didn't work for me. I am probably doing it wrong so please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a folder called `Helper` and try this:

```
<roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="MvcApplication6.Helper.CustomRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
</roleManager>
```

**One more thing**: Make sure you implement the CustomRoleProvider in a right way:
using System;
using System.Web.Security;

```
namespace MvcApplication6.Helper
{
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            if (username.ToLowerInvariant() == "test" && roleName.ToLowerInvariant() == "User")
                return true;
            // blabla ...
            return false;
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            if (username.ToLowerInvariant() == "test")
            {
                return new[] { "User", "Helpdesk" };
            }

            if(username.ToLowerInvariant()=="test2")
            {
                return new [] { "Admin" };
            }

            return new string[] { };
        }

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }        

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }        

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but why did i have to omit `defaultProvider ="roleProvider" enabled="true"` ? if i put them back in, i get the error again.

Comment: @You don't need to specify the default membership provider: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx

Comment: what about the `enabled` ? I get the errors as well if i put it back.

Comment: @CarloBrew Now, what's the problem?!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420802/custom-role-provider-in-asp-mvc Please check this, first post.

Comment: @CarloBrew now check the answer.

Comment: update: error is changed to this now `'Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Security.RoleProvider'.`

Comment: Have you implemented the RoleProvider?