# Custom role provider in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello i am kinda at lost here and i don't know what to fix:

The issue is that, my application still doesn't detect the **roles** assigned.
Like if i have something like
`[Authorize(Roles="user")]`. It won't detect my login and won't allow me to proceed on that view.

I've been following a bad tutorial and here's what i have to so far:
(i want to make it first at least before i move on to another one)

Here are my database tables:

I didn't put any hash yet for simplicity:

**Login table**

[image]

**roles table**

[image]

I use `inner join` and i will have something like this

`select A.username, A.role from login A INNER JOIN roles B on A.role = B.id`

[image]

I use code first EF 4.0 and here are my code snippets:

I have a class `roleprovider` which inherits from `roleprovider`.

I only implemented 2 methods from it, namely: `GetRolesForUser` and `IsUserInRole`

**GetRolesForUser**

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string uname)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var cacheKey = string.Format("{0_role}", uname);
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
        {
            return (string[])HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
        }

        string[] roles = new string[] { };
        using (EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext())
        {
            roles = (from a in emp.login
                     join b in emp.roles on a.role equals b.id
                     where a.username.Equals(uname)
                     select b.role).ToArray<string>();
            if (roles.Count() > 0)
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, roles, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_cacheTimeoutInMinute), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }
        return roles;
    }
```

**IsUserInRole**

```
public override bool IsUserInRole(string uname, string roleName)
{
     var userRoles = GetRolesForUser(uname);
     return userRoles.Contains(roleName);
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<roleManager>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="roleprovider"  type="MvcApplication6.Helper.roleprovider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I apologize if i can't explain the code properly as of now because i am still in the process of learning it. My primary agenda as of now i to make the code work first but i am somehow lost because i am not particularly sure of what i am missing.

Recap of the issue:
-Application won't detect the roles from the database and won't let me proceed if i try logging in.

edit: here is my login code( i have authentication mode implemented )

```
   [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("login")]
    public ActionResult login_load()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("login")]

    public ActionResult login_post(string uname,string pword)
    {
        using (EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext())
        {

            int success = emp.login.Where(x => x.username == uname && x.password == pword).Count();
            if (success == 1)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(uname, false);

                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Enrollment");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Application won't detect the roles from the database" is a little vague. What happens exactly?

Comment: It won't let me proceed even if i have [Authorize(Roles="users")] and my current login role is `users`. Let me edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips from looking at the code you posted.

Your web.config should look something like:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="roleprovider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="roleprovider"  type="MvcApplication6.Helper.roleprovider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I.e. you need to declare your custom roleprovider as the default provider.

You shold remove the following from your `GetRolesForUser` method:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return null;
}
```

The purpose of this method is to get the roles for the username passed as an argument - it shouldn't be concerned with the current user.

If this doesn't work, try putting a breakpoint in your `GetRolesForUser` method.

Comment: I tried your web config before but i get something like `parser error`. I have to use this one to avoid it.

Comment: Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420291/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-from-assembly/32420477?noredirect=1#comment52706815_32420477

Comment: @Carlo - that error message says it can't find your custom roleprovider class.  Which is a step forward from what you have now, because it's at least trying to load it.  You need to check that the name of the provider class (including namespace), and the name of the assembly that contains it match what you have in web.config.

Comment: Where do i find the assembly? and namespaces, isnt it supposed to be `MvcApplication6.Helper.roleprovider` ? My project structure can be found from my other SO question.

Comment: You shouldn't have accepted the incorrect answer to that other question.  The namespace is in the source file roleprovider.cs, by default with the project structure you posted the full class name will be MvcApplication6.roleprovider.

Comment: I changed it to `<add name="roleprovider"  type="MvcApplication6.roleprovider, MvcApplication6"/>` and `<add name="roleprovider"  type="MvcApplication6.roleprovider"/>` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by fixing my Web.Config(then everything just worked magically). It wasn't working because messed up namespaces. Full credits to Joe for the idea.